# Ovh object analysis

Tags: object, amazon-s3, cloud, ovh

**Context**:
I currently have a project where several audio files (wav) are saved using OVH cloud. This objects are managed   from my application using the S3 APIs.

**Issue**:
A member from my team, needs to somehow be able to analize this files without having to download them but I'm unsure where to start looking. What would I need to build so he can analize those files online, thanks in advance. If any information is missing let me know.

I tried looking in  S3 API [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html)
OVH documentation and ovh
[documentation](https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/de-documentation-storage-object-storage?id=kb_browse_cat&kb_id=38e74da5a884a950f07829d7d5c75217&kb_category=b29021c8e5a5edd0f078850a25104df8)  but I was not able to find something related to what I need to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "be able to analize this files without having to download" ?

S3 API at OVH or AWS is not to "analyze" files. If by analyze you mean check the content, maybe do some edit, etc. You'll need to download the file anyway. The best way to do that without the need to download the file over the Internet is to boot up a small Public Cloud Instance at OVH (EC2 equivalent) and use that to access the object storage and do whatever you need to do to those files :)

Comment: I would need to build something (maybe an api).Tere is no specific activity I can declare right now as it can vary depending on the type of audio. The main concept is thatI need  to build something  that can feed a python resource 

If you need a specific use case we can start with the following example:
The python function that takes and audio file as input and computes the average loudness of it. The parameter 'loudness' will be put into a json file in the relative field. The json file is the real output of the method.